# Changing transform-origin using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using code below to change the transform-origin but each time I got this error:

> app.min.js:3 actionator::exeJavaScript - this.execUserJs is not a function

Here is the code:

```
var item = $('.slide-object.slide-object-vectorshape.shown[data-model-id="62wRqp3LlYN_pointer"]')

$(item).css({
  'transform-origin': 124px 124px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 124px 124px;
});
```

The selector works ok, but I can't find a working way to change the `transform-origin` in Chrome? What am I missing and how can I fix this?

Comment: You don't need to wrap your `-webkit-transform-origin` with a quote?

Comment: Without wanting to sound unnecessarily hard on you, I would suggest you research a basic Javascript tutorial which covers syntax. You've asked quite a few questions this morning which have all been typos, or simple misunderstandings.

Comment: People really shouldn't even be posting answers for a simple error like this, instead add a comment and vote to close. I'd expect members with 20-30k reputation to know better than that.

Comment: Seems that people prefer to help not complaining...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you are passing to `.css` is not a valid object..

```
$(item).css({
    'transform-origin': '124px 124px',
    '-webkit-transform-origin': '124px 124px'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `-webkit-transform-origin` property will give you a parse error. Wrap it in quotes:

```
'-webkit-transform-origin': ...
```